# Installing a bff even if it is already installed

Tags: aix

I want to install a bff package even if it is already installed on the system.

Is there an equivalent to rpm --replacepkgs option for installp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [`-F` option to installp](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=i-installp-command) will:

> force the installation of a software product even if there exists a previously installed version of the software product that is the same as or newer than the version currently being installed.

Note that:

> The -F flag is not valid with update packages or the -g flag. When you use the -F flag, the -I flag is implicit.